# I have problem in a emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have problem in emulator. When I start my application it says:

```
PANIC: Could not open: C:\Users\Administrator\.android/avd/MonoDroid.ini
```

What I can do to solve this?

Comment: First, check your right to access file "MonoDroid.ini". If it works, provide more information, like your emulator version, google sdk includes or emulator from a specific hardware company?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a environment variable called: ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
2. Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences and click in Run/Debug and String Substitution
3. Add a new variable called: user.home and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
4. Restart Eclipse.
5. Create an AVD and run it.

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The path isn't correct...find .android folder on your comp and copy at  C:\Users\Administrator folder...this should do the job...