# Not able to launch android emulator in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-emulator

I created an avd and tried to launch it. Now I got the message "PANIC: Could not open: /home/my user/.android/avd/2.1.ini"  I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and Eclipse.

I check /home/my user/.android/avd/ location. There was no such file. Searched the whole hard disk, there was no such file.

Comment: Does Eclipse have the read permission on ~/.android ?
In fact the avd folder is the folder where your virtual devices are saved. So it cannot open it, it cannot execute the emulator. You can try to recreate a virtual device. Or try to reinstall the SDK.

Comment: try lookin in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936230/android-emulator-error2011-08-02-111401-emulator-panic-could-not-open-c

Comment: try to duplicate the symlink in the same way. find the file `2.1.ini`, which has to be somewhere if you installed SDK and 2.1 AVD properly, and make symlink to folder it is

Comment: @bmargulies  You says this is not a real problem. But the fact is I'm not the only one who's facing this issue. Check Marek Sebera's link.

Comment: @casperOne  You says this is not a real problem. But the fact is I'm not the only one who's facing this issue. Check Marek Sebera's link.

Comment: @Marek Sebera Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: @bmargulies a question with more than 1000 views seems useless for you??

Comment: @casperOne a question with more than 1000 views seems useless for you??

Comment: Any way I found this issue resolved on next Ubuntu update. Don't know what really happened!