# "Starting emulator for AVD" then Panic: could not open..."

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, panic

I'm new to android app dev. When I created a new AVD, when I click start on this AVD: I get the following:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus_4_16_AVD'
PANIC: Could not open: Nexus_4_16_AVD
```

[image]

Answer (score 30):

This is a bug in the ADT Plugin. For a workaround until it is fixed use a NTFS symbolic link.

I have a C: drive for windows 7 and a D: drive for all my work and data. After installing windows 7 I relocate all my special folders from C:\Users\John Doe to D:\John Doe. The ADT Plugin is trying to load the emulator from C: when it and the configure files are on D: (PANIC: Could not open etc.). NTFS can get the ADT Plugin to read from D: using a NTFS symbolic link. Open a command prompt in C:\Users\John Doe (obviously use your user name), use the mklink command.

```
 mklink /J "C:\Users\John Doe\\.android" "D:\John Doe\\.android"
```

Now when the ADT plugin is trying to reference .android on C:, NTFS sends the request to D: and the emulator starts correctly.

[Original Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936230/android-emulator-error2011-08-02-111401-emulator-panic-could-not-open-c?rq=1)

OR

If it is not a path issue, then:

Create a environment variable called: `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and set it to `C:\Users\Administrator Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences` and click in `Run/Debug` and String Substitution Add a new variable called: user.home and set it to `C:\Users\Administrator` Create an AVD and run it.

[Original Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009872/android-eclipse-panic-could-not-open/9010020#9010020)

Comment: I tried your latter solution. I can't even create a AVD now, with the ERROR:                                     [2013-08-30 18:33:29 - SDK Manager] Error: null

Comment: I'll try your former soln. What's so special about the D drive? How do you know that's where the emulator and config files are? When I looked at my Path listed in AVD details, it seems to point to the appropriate folder, containing "config.ini" and "userdata.img"

Comment: mklink worked for me as trying to move/replace the emulator manager would always try to re-write to the wrong folder

Answer (score 11):

Simply if nothing works for you, just copy the .android folder to C:\Users\.android.

Comment: I did not ask this question but found this thread as I had the same problem!

Comment: Worked for me too. +1 I guess everytime I create a new avd I have to update my C:\ folder since it gets created in the D:\

Comment: @Surya How do I do this on XP?

Comment: @Volatil3 copy the .android folder to C:\Users\YourName\.android or to C:\Users\.android

Comment: thanks this works :D
i tried to create a mklink but it was already there, the difference was that .android folder in my c drive was having different content that the one in d drive, so copying content helped

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and the first Umer Farooq's suggestion solved it. 
There was already the folder .android in C:/Users/MyName folder. I compressed it to the .android.zip for the backup purpose, and then deleted the folder C:/Users/MyName/.android. Then I opened a command prompt (it was already located at C:/Users/MyName) and executed a command:

```
 mklink /J "C:\Users\MyName\\.android" "D:\\.android"
```

Then I restarted eclipse and launched the AVD. The virtual device has been created and it worked well.

Comment: your solution works, what surprises me is that the bug is not fixed yet (nov 2014)

Answer (score 1):

my avd was in folder d:\c_data.android. it was searching in folder c:\users\rkk.android.
i copied avd folder from d:\ and pasted in c:\users\rkk.android. And it was success.