# Android Virtual Device, is not getting launch, help me

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am beginner in Android and want to create AVD but it is not getting launch and giving some error.

Error Trace:

```
[2014-03-21 17:47:58 - HelloWorld] Android Launch! [2014-03-21 17:47:58 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally. 
[2014-03-21 17:47:58 - HelloWorld] Performing in.example.HelloWorld.MainActivity activity launch 
[2014-03-21 17:47:58 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.     
[2014-03-21 17:48:01 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android'     
[2014-03-21 17:48:01 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: Android
```

Comment: @sid image is not getting upload.

Comment: You can post your error here.

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317789/how-to-create-a-new-avd-in-eclipse

Comment: [2014-03-21 17:47:58 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2014-03-21 17:47:58 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-21 17:47:58 - HelloWorld] Performing in.example.HelloWorld.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-21 17:47:58 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-03-21 17:48:01 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android'
[2014-03-21 17:48:01 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: Android

Comment: Hope, it will make you understand @Sid

Comment: @Prashant : Did you try with the solution provided by TheMohanAhuja?

Comment: If above link doesn't worked then See this link it has same problem as yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540607/starting-emulator-for-avd-then-panic-could-not-open

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do some research over **google** before putting questions here

There are some links that might solve your problem please check them out:

[how to create a new AVD in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317789/how-to-create-a-new-avd-in-eclipse)

As per your error trace: `PANIC: Could not open: Android` This link may help you:

["Starting emulator for AVD" then Panic: could not open..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540607/starting-emulator-for-avd-then-panic-could-not-open)