# Android Studio: Cannot launch AVD emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I did search around here and found many questions similar to this but none of them had problem like I did.

Well basically I try to launch my emulator but it is not working. I get pop up like this :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBAK2.png)

Any ideas how to fix this problem? Running on Windows7!

EDIT: Yes this is AVD. I tried create several more with jellybean, kitkat and others.

Comment: Since you didn't tell, is it an AVD you just created ? Did you try creating an new one ?

Comment: @brainsandwich edited. Yes and tried several other devices

Comment: any spaces in your $HOME PATH ?

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi im quite new to this but if u mean this path: Path: D:\USERS\user\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_17.avd then no spaces

Comment: Do you have the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable set up? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042638/how-do-i-set-android-sdk-home-environment-variable for how to do it. This looks similar to an error I had when it wasn't set up properly.

Comment: @Ewald thank you. Found solution for my problem and posted it as answer.

Comment: @osiic21 Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can close this!

Answer is here:

["Starting emulator for AVD" then Panic: could not open..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540607/starting-emulator-for-avd-then-panic-could-not-open)

Basically just copy d/.../.android content to c/.../.android folder and it will work.