# Can't start an Android virtual device

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just installed android ADT with eclipse on a win 7 pc 32 bit.

When I create the AVD, it can't start. I get a msg "Panic, could not open Test1".

I have read several threads about this issue.

I have created enviroment variable C:\Users\myusername.

I  have added in eclipse under preferences..run/debug--string substitution: variable user.home, value: c:\users\myusername.

still devices don't run.

When I check the AVD manager, O see it pointing at:

```
\\servername\Home\myusername\.android\avd.
```

I can actually open that folder and see the devices created so I am confused.

I have admin rights on the PC but is part of a lan.

Any suggestions please!

Answer (score 0):

please check the following post

[android emulator error:[2011-08-02 11:14:01 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: C:\Users\hallo\.android/avd/myemu.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936230/android-emulator-error2011-08-02-111401-emulator-panic-could-not-open-c)

hope it can help you

Comment: Have tried all suggestions in the thread...but no luck...created environmental variable \\servername\Home\myusername.  added it under preferences...but still same error!...the AVD manager points to \\serveername\Home\myname\.android\avd.