# developing android apps with eclipse

Tags: java, android, plugins, bundle

I am new to android development and I can't seem to get it to work.
I have downloaded the Android ADT bundle, which contains:

- Eclipse + ADT plugin
- Android SDK Tools
- Android Platform-tools
- The latest Android platform
- The latest Android system image for the emulator

But when I try to run my project the consol print out:

```
[2013-06-27 12:46:08 - FirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-06-27 12:46:08 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-27 12:46:08 - FirstApp] Performing com.example.firstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-06-27 12:46:08 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MyLG'
[2013-06-27 12:46:08 - FirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MyLG'
[2013-06-27 12:46:09 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: MyLG
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103782/avd-panic-could-not-open-not-a-path-issue

Answer (score 0):

Please configure the emulator Properly.

Comment: hmm I hope i'm not asking a stupid question now.. but how do I configure my emulator "properly" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try check here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

or

http://alvinalexander.com/android/android-eclipse-create-android-virtual-device-avd

Best regards,

Comment: okay, i tried creating a new avs.. But I still get the same messages:
 
[2013-06-28 15:04:25 - FirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-06-28 15:04:25 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-28 15:04:25 - FirstApp] Performing com.example.firstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-06-28 15:04:26 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MadsSmartPhone'
[2013-06-28 15:04:26 - FirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MadsSmartPhone'
[2013-06-28 15:04:27 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: MadsSmartPhone