# Android virtual Device not starting on a fresh android sdk installation

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying android development from last week.I am following the hello world tutorial given on the Android official site and following each step. But my avd is not starting . I am using windows 7 and i have downloaded the latest sdk. Here is the screen shot[image: screen shote]

[image: settings]

Comment: whats is the issue when u start the emulator?

Comment: i have added the screen shot. Plz check it

Comment: can you show us the emulator/avd settings?

Comment: i am using the pre defined nexus one.. uploaded screen shot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103782/avd-panic-could-not-open-not-a-path-issue  see this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure :
Create a environment variable called: ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences and click in Run/Debug and String Substitution
Add a new variable called: user.home and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
Create an AVD and run it.

Alternate solution i would suggest u is use android app player :

[Bluestack](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

OR

[YouWave](http://youwave.com/)

Comment: OR rather post ur screen shot here

Comment: ok . i will try that :). But still i also want to run it from avd

Comment: r u facing problem in creating specific avd?

Comment: no.. i am following the tutorial from developers.android.com ..  tell me how to do that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35188/discussion-between-abhigyan-sen-and-stacks28)

Answer (score 0):

First a fall check whether ".android folder" is present in your C: Drive or not

If not Copy ".android folder" to C: drive

The exact path have to be like this

C:\Users\.android

Ok,Try this....

Answer (score 0):

I too got the similar problem, the way I solved it using the following steps

1. Choose Run Configurations from Run in the menu bar.
2. Under the Android Application --> Select New Configuration.
3. In the Android Tab give the configuration a name.
4. Browse for your project in the project list
5. Select Launch radio button in the Launch Action Tab and choose your package name and Click on Apply.
6. In the Target Tab Click on the "Always prompt to device" radio button and select your AVD which you have created already.
7. Click on Apply and then Run.
8. Now your AVD is ready to take off.