# Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD-Galaxy'

Tags: android, android-emulator

When starting the emulator in Android SDK it cannot open the respective AVD. The error is:

```
PANIC: Could not open: AVD-Galaxy.
```

I tried changing the path but it did not seem to have any effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103782/avd-panic-could-not-open-not-a-path-issue

Comment: It's not the response what you exactly want, but maybe you could try the Genymotion simulator, it's way better then the AVD emulator

Answer (score 0):

may be your avd's sdk in not installed so go in sdk manager and try to install that sdk level like for example if your avd version is 17 and you dont have that sdk then it will give this error

Answer (score 0):

By default RAM will size will be more than 1GB while creating new AVD. so most of the system will start not able to start the created AVD. so set RAM size 400 - 600MB and try.