# Running the project causing an error

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to run the project in android studio and then i found this

PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: C:\Users\Aftab.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd\config.ini

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVD - PANIC: Could not open... - not a path issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103782/avd-panic-could-not-open-not-a-path-issue)

Comment: you have not installed Android Studio properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. delete avd in avd manager
2. Go to folder  C:\Users\Aftab.android\avd\

and delete  Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd

3. create a new avd

Hope this works