# Eclipse AVD doesnt work

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device, panic

Unfortunately I failted to start an AVD. In the two pictures you see;

1. My settings

2. The second (and last) screen after start.

Can anyone please help me? :D

[image: [one][1] <br>]
[image]

Comment: Try to check the "Use Host GPU" option then run the emulator.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084

Answer (score 0):

from this so [answer from COLIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9010020/931982)

> 1. Create a environment variable called: ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
> 2. Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences and click in Run/Debug and String Substitution
> 3. Add a new variable called: user.home and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
> 4. Create an AVD and run it.

Comment: Keep getting te same PANIC thing such that it doesnt start.

Answer (score 0):

Go for this two links which i'm giving..it is nicely explained step-by-step...[Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)    and [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-virtual-device-creation/)
i'm sure it will help you...Enjoy...:D