# eclipse android emulator not starting

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I have some problems with my emulator in eclipse. When I create an AVD and start it, the emulator is running and showing the "Android" logo/text, but never moves on from there.

Should I set some specific settings when I create a new AVD to make it run faster?
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: It may be helpful if, in the title of this question, you mentioned which operating system you're running under (Mint, Debian, Mac O/S, Windows, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have issues with `AVD`, I'd highly encourage to try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: Im trying to use the genymotion plugin in eclipse but gets the following error:
Genymotion directory is not set.

Comment: I guess you'll need to configure `Genymobile` prefs in `Eclipse=>Preferences`. Anyway, you should be able to start Genymotion as a standalone app, once you run a device simulator, Eclipse will detect it as an available android device.

Comment: Glad you did it :) Enjoy!

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more than once. What a blessing! Speed, fluidity, resizing, rotation, it's all there. Amazing!

Answer (score 4):

If You have a PC/Laptop with less than 4GB RAM the emulator will take some time to start up and it will run very slow.
Additionally You can tick a box called Use Host GPU in the Emulation Options while crating a new AVD.

Comment: I tried ticking the "use host gpu", but i's still running unbelievable slow :( thanks for your advice though.. it may be my slow processor's fault.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a processor that supports `VT-x, EM64T, and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality` or in simple terms a `core i processor`, download *intel HAXM android emulator*. It is much faster then the default android emulator comes bundled.

Here is the link: [***Intel HAXM Android EMUALTOR***](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-microsoft)

Comment: I've tried, but i get this error message while starting:
Starting emulator for AVD 'newphone'
emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
emulator: Open HAX device failed
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

Comment: You are trying to start a emulator using HAXM emulation (requiring an Intel processor, and a plugin installed).  Remove the 'Hardware Acceleration' checkmark from your AVD.

Comment: This is fantastic. More people need to know about this!

Answer (score 0):

You may have snapshots enabled, in which case, ensure you are selecting 'Wipe Device' in the device manager when you start it.

I would also suggest you just create a new AVD instance, and start from scratch - this doesn't take very long, and will likely be quicker than trying to debug a failing instance.

Comment: I've tried creating new AVD a couple of times, but it is still running really slow. What should the AVD be configured? (optimal settings?)

Answer (score 0):

Use lower specifications for your Android Emulator other than using a host GPU as mentioned by [PLG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19338350/4282901). For details refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32629822/4282901).