# Android emulator launched but not opening

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi i'm new to Android few days before i installed ADT. From starting day Emulator is not starting but it's launched. It's showing launching status from 2 hours but not starting. For understanding see this [URL](http://s13.postimg.org/jhyv3s9tz/Capture.png) (i'm not able to post a image in StackOverflow bcz of that i'm using other resource)

Comment: I suggest you to use Genymotion (http://www.genymotion.com/), which is much easier than AVD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse android emulator not starting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338270/eclipse-android-emulator-not-starting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downgrading the specs of your emulator i.e. use smaller screen size, use less memory size etc.

```
e.g. Device: Nexus 7 
     CPU: ARM
     Skin: QVGA
     Front Camera: None
     Back Camera: None
     Memory Options: 1024
     Heap:32
     SD: 10 MiB
     Internal Storage: 200Mib
     Use Host GPU
```

[image: Emulator Specs]

**PS**: No need to wait for more than 5 Minutes :)

Comment: I don't know what happened to my emulator. I tried this solution when "Syed Osama Maruf" answered but it's not worked at that time. But it's working now. It's really shock to me......Thank you Syed Osama Maruf