# Android emulator not starting on eclipse

Tags: android, c, eclipse

I am getting the below error when trying to start an `Android` emulator from `Eclipse`:

```
[2013-01-03 15:10:28 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: test
```

Please note that its not same to the error:

```
[2011-07-10 15:32:26 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open:C:\Users\Sam\.android/avd/Android2.1.ini
```

Where , `ini` file is giving the error. Hence, solution of `mklink` will not apply in my case.

In my case `test` is the application name.

PS: I am using `Windows 7`.

Comment: what's the relation between your question and `C` flag ?

Answer (score 2):

```
I have seen the following solution somewhere.
Try this..

1) Create a environment variable called: ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
2) Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences and click in Run/Debug and String Substitution
3) Add a new variable called: user.home and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
4) Create an AVD and run it.
```

Comment: The original solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009872/android-eclipse-panic-could-not-open

Comment: I had a similar issue. Windows 7. ADT Bundle 64-bit. I was logging in to my PC with Active Directory credentials(corporate). Emulator was not starting at all, after I tried many different things. I switched to a local administrator login, and everything worked.

This is not necessarily the solution. I would rather want to know how to make it work on my AD account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before. All I did was open eclipse with administrator privilege.

i.e,

```
Right-click eclipse and 
choose 'Run as administrator'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create a environment variable called: ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set it to
>      C:\Users\Administrator
> 2. Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences and click
>      in Run/Debug and String Substitution
> 3. Add a new variable called:
>      user.home and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
> 4. Create an AVD and run
>      it.

- [Android Emulator can't start, 'cause of wrong folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641498/android-emulator-cant-start-cause-of-wrong-folder)
- [android emulator error:[2011-08-02 11:14:01 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: C:\Users\hallo\.android/avd/myemu.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936230/android-emulator-error2011-08-02-111401-emulator-panic-could-not-open-c)
- [I have problem in a emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774368/i-have-problem-in-a-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could find your solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16998114/1764416). The programmer was working on `D:` drive (where his libraries were), so he copied the `.android` folder from `D:\hisName\` to `C:\Users\hisName\`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to another post on so which i can not find anymore i used this method :

On windows 7 (perhaps on MAC too ?) :
simply delete the .android folder in your USER/ folder and voilà.

When you open eclipse or android studio, the .android folder will be recreated and your avd will run just fine.

PS : you do not need to uninstall the android sdk manager program.