# Android Studio - Panic: Could not open AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-studio

After many hours of fixing Gradle issues, I was able to build my test app in Android Studio. But when I tried to run it in an AVD, it just won't open.

This is the log:

```
Waiting for device.
C:\Users\Rahaman\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd testAVD -netspeed full -netdelay none

PANIC: Could not open: testAVD
```

P.S.: I've defined the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME to point to the .android directory.

Comment: How do you fix GRADLE issue man. Because It takes more than 15 min for me to create an Project in android studio." Building 'APPNAME' gradle project. " this dialouge box takes forever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, my libraries are in `D:` drive. 
So I had to copy the `.android` folder from `d:\myName\` to `c:\Users\myName\`. That fixed it.

Comment: can you plz say how you changed this path reference in android studio?

Comment: @mukesh You don't have to change path reference in Android Studio, just move the `.android` folder from your other drive to `c:` drive

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) (builtin of cmd.exe but NOT present in Powershell) to make a link like you would in linux.  You must be an administrator to run the command, but once you do it will look like the directory is right there.

Run cmd.exe as an administrator.  Then in my case I issued the following:

```
C:\Users\Dad>mklink /d .android E:\Joel\.android
```

Creating a regular windows shortcut (right click etc.) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I got a slightly different solution working.  I created a symlink/shortcut from `C:\Users\myName\.android` to `D:\Users\myName\.android`  (right-click, create shortcut)