# "PANIC: Could not open" while trying to run Android emulator on Linux Mint

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, adt, linux-mint

I installed Eclipse Kepler and the Android development tools. Everything is working fine, except for when I try to run my Android code in an emulator I get the following error:

```
Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: [name of Android virtual device]
```

I Googled the problem but I have not found a solution. It might have to do with the Android path or perhaps authorizations, but I do not know where I have to change them to.

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked a few times already, try this:

- Create a environment variable called: ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set it to
  C:\Users\Administrator
- Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences and click in Run/Debug and String
  Substitution
- Add a new variable called: user.home and set it to
  C:\Users\Administrator
- Create an AVD and run it.

> As a work-around, you can define the environment variable
>   ANDROID_SDK_HOME to point to the directory containing your .android
>   directory. The emulator and SDK Manager will pick it up properly.

Original answer by: [Colin Pickard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009872/android-eclipse-panic-could-not-open/9010020#9010020)

---

To change the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` variable in Ubuntu (as requested in the comment):

Edit your `.profile` file with a command like `gedit ~/.profile` and append the following to the end of the file:

`export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/your/android-sdk/path/here`

Here's a list of some variables you can modify for Android Tools.

`export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools`

`export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools`

`export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools`

`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME`

---

**Similar Questions**

[Android Emulator can't start, 'cause of wrong folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641498/android-emulator-cant-start-cause-of-wrong-folder)

[I have problem in a emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774368/i-have-problem-in-a-emulator)

[android emulator error:[2011-08-02 11:14:01 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: C:\Users\hallo\.android/avd/myemu.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936230/android-emulator-error2011-08-02-111401-emulator-panic-could-not-open-c)

Comment: I am on a Ubuntu Linux system. How exactly do I set my path variable of ANDROID_SDK_HOME? Which steps to follow?

Comment: Thanks. My Android home is `/opt/android-sdk-linux` I believe. Setting that value to `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` by running `export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux` does not help.