# Processing 2.0 - Android, cannot create AVD

Tags: android, arduino, processing, android-virtual-device

Very quick: I'm using ubuntu and want to run the android emulator (AVD) via processing.

Ok, so first I installed Android Studio (SDK), started it and ran that AVD emulator without any problems, worked fine.

BUT - I need the whole thing for Processing 2.0 (in connection with an Arduino). After setting the correct directory, I'm able to create a specific AVD - but if I want to run it: "PANIC: Could not run: " and that's it.

I tried different settings (eg. GPS on/off, RAM +/-), Android versions, etc... Nothing helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Try this [question][1]. It should get and emulator up and ready.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942497/panic-could-not-open-while-trying-to-run-android-emulator-on-linux-mint